# Laravel: Doctor hasMany Appointments and appontment hasOne rating, How to get Doctor rating

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have  Doctor table relation with appointments table, doctor can have many appointments. Appointments table relation with Ratings, one appointment (**only completed**) can have rating.
I want avg rating of doctors all appointments. for example a doctor have 10 appointments and 5 of which are completed and and have rating i.e 3,4,1,3,4
I Want to show Rating for doctor as example result **3** average rate.

How I can you do this?

Comment: can you show database structure for doctor, appointments and rating table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that. I don't know the names of the attributes you are using, so I used mine.

```
$sum = 0;
$count = 0; 

foreach($doctor->appointments as $appointment){
    if($appointment->isComplete){
        $count++;
        $sum += $appointment->rating->value;
    }
}

$avg = $sum / $count;
```

Loop over the doctor appointments, for each appointment, check if it's completed, get the value of its rating.

You can make a function in the Doctor model called rating that has this logic.

**OR**

You can use the `hasManyThrough` relationship. 
[hasManyThrough - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

I'm not sure if it's applicable when the model has on-to-many relationship with the intermediate table or not .. but you can give it a try.

Comment: any other solution using laravel relationsip? I have alredy done using foreach but I want to simply it by using relationships. any idea?